# Linewrap in legend in pgfplots [Solved]

Tags: pgfplots, plot, legend

I try make plot with long text in legend.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,-0.13)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left},
tick label style={font=\tiny\scriptsize},
legend style={font=\scriptsize},
axis lines=left,
legend style={draw=none},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
height=10cm,
width=17cm,
legend columns=2,
]
\addplot[color=red, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.79489, -0.794084) 
 (-3.54497, -0.919739) 
 (-3.51697, -0.93037) 
 (-3.3082, -0.986154) 
 (-0.165787, 0.986289) 
 (0.92704, 0.600204) 
};
\addlegendentry{Long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long text};

\addplot[color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.79489, 0.607808) 
 (-3.54497, 0.39253) 
 (-3.51697, 0.366622) 
 (-3.3082, 0.165834) 
 (-0.165787, -0.165029) 
 (0.92704, 0.799847) 
};
\addlegendentry{Plot 1};

\addplot[color=green, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-2.79489, 1.607808) 
 (-2.54497, 1.39253) 
 (-2.51697, 1.366622) 
 (-2.3082, 1.165834) 
 (-2.165787, -1.165029) 
 (1.92704, 1.799847) 
};

\addlegendentry{Plot 3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I see that:

[image]

If I use `legend style={text width=5.5cm},` I see that:

[image]

Is it possible to wrap the text in the legend?

Comment: On the case two, after adding `text width=5.5cm`, changing `legend columns=2` into `legend columns=-1` will draw all entries horizontally, hence solve your problem in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only an example. In general, I do not know the length of each text in legend. And there may be many lines.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Corrected. Added in separate answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you! Your comments has helped to find a solution. I can use `[minimum height=0.9in]` for each label: `\addlegendentry[minimum height=0.9in]{111}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,-0.13)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left},
tick label style={font=\tiny\scriptsize},
legend style={font=\scriptsize},
axis lines=left,
legend style={draw=none},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
height=10cm,
width=17cm,
legend columns=2,
legend style={text width=5.5cm},
]
\addplot[color=red, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.79489, -0.794084) 
 (-3.54497, -0.919739) 
 (-3.51697, -0.93037) 
 (-3.3082, -0.986154) 
 (-0.165787, 0.986289) 
 (0.92704, 0.600204) 
};
\addlegendentry[minimum height=0.9in]{
Long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long text};

\addplot[color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.79489, 0.607808) 
 (-3.54497, 0.39253) 
 (-3.51697, 0.366622) 
 (-3.3082, 0.165834) 
 (-0.165787, -0.165029) 
 (0.92704, 0.799847) 
};
\addlegendentry{Plot 1};

\addplot[color=yellow, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3., -0.607808) 
 (-3.97, 0.39253) 
 (-3.1697, 0.366622) 
 (-3.082, 0.165834) 
 (-0.65787, -0.165029) 
 (0.2704, 0.799847) 
};
\addlegendentry{Plot 1 4 4 6465 46 46 46};

\addplot[color=black, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.9489, 0.07808) 
 (-3.4497, 0.9253) 
 (-3.1697, 0.66622) 
 (-3.082, 0.65834) 
 (-0.65787, -0.65029) 
 (0.2704, 0.99847) 
};
\addlegendentry{Plot new test};

\addplot[color=green, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.9489, 0.47808) 
 (-3.4497, -0.3253) 
 (-3.1697, 0.36622) 
 (-3.082, 0.15834) 
 (-0.65787, -0.05029) 
 (0.2704, 0.09847) 
};
\addlegendentry{Plot new test};

\addlegendentry{Plot 3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A legend is a `node`, You can specify the `minimum height` and `text width` etc:

```
 \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.9,
    every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,-0.13)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left},
    tick label style={font=\tiny\scriptsize},
    legend style={draw=none,
              font=\scriptsize,
              text width=2in,           %% adjust
              minimum height=0.5in,     %% adjust
              %anchor=center,
              %cells={anchor=west},
            },
    %axis lines=left,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
height=10cm,
width=11cm,
legend columns=2,
]
\addplot[color=red, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.79489, -0.794084)
 (-3.54497, -0.919739)
 (-3.51697, -0.93037)
 (-3.3082, -0.986154)
 (-0.165787, 0.986289)
 (0.92704, 0.600204)
};
\addlegendentry{Long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long text};

\addplot[color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-3.79489, 0.607808)
 (-3.54497, 0.39253)
 (-3.51697, 0.366622)
 (-3.3082, 0.165834)
 (-0.165787, -0.165029)
 (0.92704, 0.799847)
};
\addlegendentry{Plot 1};

\addplot[color=green, mark=*] coordinates {
 (-2.79489, 1.607808)
 (-2.54497, 1.39253)
 (-2.51697, 1.366622)
 (-2.3082, 1.165834)
 (-2.165787, -1.165029)
 (1.92704, 1.799847)
};

\addlegendentry{Plot 3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the distance increases for all elements. Сan I make that cell only stretched for long text?

Comment: @Harrix I am not sure :-(